# Magento community site with 2 storefronts- need to know how to define User roles in different locales.

Tags: multistore, cms, magento-community, user-roles

Hi I have a magento community site with 2 storefronts targeting different locales. The site is mainly administered from the UK but our office in Australia will need to make edits to it too. My problem lies in the CMS in that i need to make sure that the AU staff cant make any changes to anything that will affect the UK catalogue. All the products are in a shared catalogue with the ability to bespoke attributes (like price, meta) for different storefronts.
Basically I need to be able to make sure that the user roles in the website can be set up to only allow for any changes to be made in their storefront.
I was wondering if this isn't possible if there is such thing as a 'change history' defined by user?

Thanks in advance for any help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible in a default Magento store, so you should try [searching](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=magento%20admin%20permissions%20per%20store) for some modules or create one yourself if you would like this.

Change history is available if you have Magento Enterprise, but that's a rather expensive package for most small webshop owners.
There are several 3rd party for this available to if you [Google](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=magento%20admin%20actions%20log) some, but I can't recommend one since I never worked with one but the Magento Enterprise logging system.

Edit: In general, the extensions of Aheadworks are quite well build, although this module isn't out yet, maybe it can be of interest:
http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/admin-log.html

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept this answer for future users! :)