# How to track Admin user backend actions

Tags: magento-1.8, configuration, log, admin-panel

My client changed admin settings from their admin panel and they don't know what exactly they changed and updated in the configuration area.

I am calculating donation for each product based on some custom product attributes for example product type, product donation [in percentage].

But now the donation is showing Zero, I checked it but I am not getting what they changed and updated.

Is there any way to know what they changed/updated?
Is there any server log file to maintain all admin actions?

Answer (score 4):

There is some admin actions logging available in Magento Enterprise, but not in the Community edition.
If changes are made, it's impossible to view the history to check what actually changed.

Check my answer here for more info, you could install a 3rd party module to prevent this in the future:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/51578/4835

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension which you can use to see the list of actions performed by each admin users. This is paid one. Please see the below link

https://amasty.com/admin-actions-log.html

Comment: Does any minimum feature free stuff available ?

Comment: @gem Yes, Free stuff available but it's for M2.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to you, Magento does not save its old products data in the system. So you cannot get old records of products or see a change log.